# Solidity: Disable Buying and Selling if CurrentPrice is below LastTransactionPrice?

Tags: solidity

Solidity: Disable Buying and Selling if CurrentPrice is below LastTransactionPrice?

Disable Buying/Selling if the price (Ask/Bid) is below LastTransactionPrice?

Is the LatestPrice from Chainlink the LastTransactionPrice?

Where and how could I reject the Ask/Bid prices buyer and seller place?

i.e. on Pancake Swap
How to query the price of a token listed on PancakeSwap?

Thank you!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
int256 private CurrentAsk;
int256 private CurrentBid;
int256 private getLastestPrice;
constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
    priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);    
}

function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
    (
        uint80 roundID,
        int256 price,
        uint startedAt,
        uint timeStamp,
        uint80 answeredInRound
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return price;
}

function setCurrentAsk(int256 askPrice) public {
  require(askPrice > getLastestPrice,"Ask price must be higher than the lastest price");
  CurrentAsk=askPrice;
}

function setCurrentBid(int256 bidPrice) public {
  require(bidPrice > getLastestPrice, "Bid price must be higher than the latest price");
  CurrentBid=bidPrice;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi johnnybegoode! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Can you explain what's the problem? It is not clear from the description.

Comment: I would like to add a condition in my smart contract that Disables Buying and Selling if the Ask/Bid prices are below LastTransactionPrice? I need to query the Ask/Bid price of a token listed on PancakeSwap.

Comment: I can't run the contract but the only problem I see is that the variable `getLastestPrice` isn't intialized properly. I think you should add `getLastestPrice = getLatestPrice()` before the require statement in both `setCurrentAsk` and `setCurrentBid`.

Comment: I get ParserError: Expected identifier but got '=' after adding getLastestPrice = getLatestPrice();

Comment: I tried and it works here. Are you sure your code is exactly like the one posted here? because `getLastestPrice` and `getLatestPrice` are quite similar and are easy to mix.